# Append to a File

Tags: java, io, append, fileoutputstream, printwriter

I am trying to write a java program that appends the current date and time of the system to a log file (that gets run by a batch file at my computer startup). Here's is my code.

```
public class LogWriter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* open the write file */
        FileOutputStream f=null;
        PrintWriter w=null;

        try {
            f=new FileOutputStream("log.txt");
            w=new PrintWriter(f, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Can't write file");
        }

        /* replace this with your own username */
        String user="kumar116";
        w.append(user+"\t");

        /* c/p http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/ */
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        w.append(dateFormat.format(date)+'\n');

        /* close the write file*/
        if(w!=null) {
            w.close();
        }

    }

}
```

The problem is, it's not appending :) to the file. Can someone point out what is the problem here ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PrintWriter#append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#append%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) does not append data to a file. Instead it performs a direct `write` using the `Writer`. You need to declare your `FileOutputStream` constructor using an append flag:

```
f = new FileOutputStream("log.txt", true);
w = new PrintWriter(f); // autoflush not required provided close is called
```

The `append` method may still be used or more convenient is `println` which will not require a newline character to be added:

```
w.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

The autoflush flag in the `PrintWriter` constructor is not required provided close is called. `close` should appear in a `finally` block.

Comment: you should add a ` after Writer. As it is, it looks rather bad: `Writer. You need to declare your `FileOutputStream`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `PrintWriter` constructor doesn't take a parameter for deciding to append to a file or not.  It controls autoflushing.

Create a [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) (which can control whether to append to a file), then wrap that stream in your `PrintWriter`.

```
try {
    f=new FileOutputStream("log.txt", true);
    w=new PrintWriter(f, true);  // This true doesn't control whether to append
}
```